# PostgreSQL не создает таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, heroku

Работаю с ботом для Telegram, деплой и БД делаю на базе Heroku. Имею следующий код создания таблицы и последующего выдергивания столбца из нее:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_info.get('NAME'), user=db_info.get('USER'), password=db_info.get('PASSWORD'), host=db_info.get('HOST'), port=db_info.get('PORT'))
    c = conn.cursor()
    kom = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ch_{} (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nickname   VARCHAR)".format(chat_id)
    c.execute(kom)
    c.close()
    conn.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['register'])
def reg_user(message):
    chat_id = str(message.chat.id)[1:]
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_info.get('NAME'), user=db_info.get('USER'), password=db_info.get('PASSWORD'), host=db_info.get('HOST'), port=db_info.get('PORT'))
    c = conn.cursor()
    try:
        kom = "SELECT nickname FROM ch_{}".format(chat_id)
        curs = c.execute(kom)
        data = curs.fetchall()
```

Таблица не создается, о чем говорит traceback

```
File "D:/Programming/python/mason4pdabot/UselessBot.py", line 32, in reg_user
    curs = c.execute(kom)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "ch_33578100" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT nickname FROM ch_33578100
```

Хотя предварительная запись таблицы никаких ошибок не возвращает. Делаю вывод что не создается таблица. Как узнать по какой причине/где можно посмотреть логи? Или в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что, `postgresql` разрешает `varchar` без указания размера? что говорит тот же `traceback` на создание таблицы (`c.execute(kom)`)?

Comment: Я практически уверен что тоблица создалась, но с другим chat_id. Вы можете сделать запрос на то какие таблицы существуют?

Comment: @Akina создание разрешает, traceback молчит

Comment: @AndrioSkur посмотреть возможности нет, но если верить мониторингу с Heroku, то по его данным, никаких таблиц в нем вообще нет.

Comment: вы можете выкинуть из кода все кроме создания таблицы и подключиться к базе чтобы мониторить какие запросы на неё идут?

Comment: вызовите `conn.commit()` после `c.execute()` при создании таблицы

Comment: @godva а вот теперь появилось. Оформите как ответ?